# Fearing rejection from others and hence hesitant about it

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Is there a term for the situation when we falter about making a suggestion or flinch from giving an answer or hesitating to take an action fearing ridicule of others or their rejection?

Is there a sort of a phobia for it, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a symptom of Kakarrhaphiophobia, the fear of being rejected.

This is a fantastic word...........perfect for a spelling bee!

Answer (score 3):

**[Atychiphobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atychiphobia)** *aka* Kakarrhaphiophobia

> A person afflicted with atychiphobia considers the possibility of failure so intense that they choose not to take the risk. Often this person will subconsciously undermine their own efforts so that they no longer have to continue to try.[4] Because effort is proportionate to the achievement of personal goals and fulfillment, this unwillingness to try that arises from the perceived inequality between the possibilities of success and failure holds the atychiphobic back from a life of meaning and the realization of potential.

Comment: this is by far the best definition I got. it clears things up. thanks.

Comment: May I please get you to inline-mention that this is a Wikipedia citation? There is a new meta question about attributions you may also wish to look at. thanks.

Comment: @tchrist I'm not sure I understand the first part. Also, can you pl direct me to the 'meta question' mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

I can also add:

[Gelotophobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelotophobia): Fear of being ridiculed/laughed at.

Comment: that will help. thumbs up.

Comment: Relevant, though *gelotophobia* is **too literally** the fear of being laughed it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "insecure?"

> **insecure**: subject to fears, etc., not self-confident or assured.

Comment: I think you described the feeling well, but what about the fear of it. I am feeling insecure but what what is making me so?

Comment: @vickyace: Presumably, a lack of self-confidence.

Comment: No attribution on this one at all. Please fix.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- shy: being reserved or having or showing nervousness or timidity in the company of other people.
- hesitant: tentative, unsure, or slow in acting or speaking.
- apprehensive: anxious or fearful that something bad or unpleasant will happen.

Comment: Where are those citations from? Please tell us the name of where you got those from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 0):

Costive: [2. slow in action or in expressing ideas, opinions, etc](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/costive).